# how to change the color of fields in the following code and how do we get that color as we have not defined any color in css?

Tags: html, css, angular

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fyzdvb?file=index.html
I am new to CSS and HTML can anyone help me with that color of the field?

Answer (score 0):

You can install extensions on your web browser to do this job. Searching for keywords like "color picker" or "eyedropper" will do.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can change the color of fields by adding some color for those fields on *input-overview-example.css* like this:

   ```
    .example-form
    {
          background-color:aqua;
          border-color: red;
          //.....
     }
    .example-full-width
    {
          color:blue;
          //...
    }
    .mat-input-element 
    {
        color: #673ab7;
        //...
    }
   ```
2. If you wanna get that color as you have, you can add-on the extension on browser such as **ColorZilla** on Chrome. You can google that extension.

Comment: In this, I can only see background-color is only working I want to change violet color which is coming when we try to enter data in the fields

Comment: @tejamandadapu: You can add like this to input-overview-example.css :
.mat-input-element {
    color: #673ab7;
}

Comment: Sorry @don lee I have tried it too it is not working I want to change the color of the input field when the mat-form field is hover. The following is the link to input overview example https://stackblitz.com/angular/gjvkdaqbjxne?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-overview-example.css

Comment: Hmm. I tried to add  .mat-input-element { color: #673ab7; } to input-overview-example.css and the input text changed to violet color.

Comment: ::ng-deep .mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
  /*change color of label*/
  color: green !important;
 }

 ::ng-deep.mat-form-field-underline {
  /*change color of underline*/
  background-color: green !important;
} 

::ng-deep.mat-form-field-ripple {
 /*change color of underline when focused*/
 background-color: green !important;;
}  @don lee the following code is working